# How do I empty a directory without iterating over it?

Tags: python, file, file-handling

Let's consider that I have a non-empty folder path:

```
dir = r'D:\ZIP_Or_Installations';
```

I want to empty this folder, but without iterating over the contents inside it(because I am seeking performance optimal solution over here).

I can't seem to find the appropriate function. I've tried to use `shutil.rmtree()` but use of this function must point strictly to a non-empty directory, which means it will eradicate the entire directory which is something I do not want.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time looking into this post.

Comment: You talk about emptying a directory, but then "eradicate the entire directory is not what you want' ?

Comment: Once we had a similar problem with 1000's of files in about 60 nested folders. Our solution was to remove the parent directory and replace it. Worked very well, except IT went mental as their server was trying to keep up by checking the existence of each file...

Comment: What is your OS, Windows or Ubuntu ?

Comment: @azro, yes that's exactly what I seek.

Comment: @MinaAbdEl-Massih, my OS is windows.

Comment: You want to empty it but keep the folder (empty so) ? Use `shutil.rmtree()` then re-create the dir with `os.mkdir`

Comment: *Why* don't you want to delete the directory? Is some other process going to break if it tries to access the directory before you can recreate it?

Comment: @chepner He can put the code of recreating right after the one that removes the directory, the code of creation is very fast anyway, it doesn't take long.

Comment: @MinaAbdEl-Massih "Doesn't take long" is still a window where it can happen. It's a legitimate reason for not wanting to delete the directory; I'm just trying to establish if it *is* the reason.

Comment: @chepner, the reason why I don't look for a solution where I delete the folder and re-create it is because I want to keep other user processes asynchronous to this folder. I mean if two users are accessing the same folder, I delete it, this will cause FileNotFoundError to the other user.

Comment: @GauravTiwari You can always add an if condition at both of you which checks whether the directory exists or not and if it does don't create it and if it's not there then one of you can create it.

Comment: @GauravTiwari Just to note, if the other programs aren't anticipating a possible `FileNotFoundError`, that's a bug in those programs, not something you should need to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

### For Ubuntu

This removes the directory and its contents:

Worth mentioning warning: **It's dangerous to run with -rf. If there is a mistake in path... could end up deleting important files.**

So make sure you are providing the correct directory.

```
import os
path = 'folder/to/clean'
os.system('rm -rf %s/*' % path)
```

If you want to keep the folder itself you can add to create the folder again in the same directory:

```
os.mkdir('path/to/folder')
```

### For Windows

You can remove folder and its contents with this (P.S. D:/test is a directory example):

```
import os
os.system('rd /s /q "D:/test"')
```

And then you can make the directory with:

```
os.mkdir("D:/test")
```

So your code should be like this:

```
import os
os.system('rd /s /q "D:/test"')
os.mkdir("D:/test")
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the directory.

Comment: I appreciate the efforts you're taking in coming up with a solution, but the same thing could be achieved using shutil.rmtree(). I've mentioned this in my question. :)